# Why do I get a copy of an object when I pass the same object into the constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor

I want to figure out what's going on here. Why do I get a copy of an object when I pass it to the constructor which expects a string parameter instead? Here is my code, just to clarify:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Person
{
public:
    Person( string name ):itsName(name){}

    /*operator std::string()
    {
        return itsName;
    }*/

    void SetName( string name )
    {
        itsName = name;
    }

    string GetName()
    {
        return itsName;
    }

private:
    string itsName;
};

int main()
{
    Person p1( "Lois" );
    Person p2( p1 );

    cout << p1.GetName() << endl;
    cout << p2.GetName();
    return 0;
}
```

Who do I see p2's name which is the same as P1's ? It is intuitive of course, but I haven't set any object as parameter in my Person constructor. It should expect a string. I did comment the overloaded string operator, which looked like the "bad guy" here, but it's not. This code compiles on Code::Blocks using MinGW ( gcc ).

Comment: You're not calling the constructor that takes a `std::string` parameter. You are using what's called a "copy constructor". See your C++ book for more information.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what did you expect to happen when you passed `p1` as a parameter to a constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sam Varshavchik said in his comment, you are using a copy constructor. This is defined implicitly for every struct, class, or union that you create under the condition that all the member variables also have a copy constructor!

What it does is takes a reference to the object in the parameter and creates a copy by calling the copy constructors for all the member variables in the object in order to create a deep copy.

If I recall correctly a default constructor is also defined implicitly in a similar way.

[cppreference on the subject](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor#Implicitly-declared_copy_constructor)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because compiler generates a default copy constructor. See [copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor).
If you don't like the default behavior, you can explicitly delete it.

```
 Person(const Person& ) = delete;
```